# EmberJS - modifying model before render and resetting during update

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

The question may be a little ambiguous. Added a JsBin example below.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/julimila/4/

I have two questions.

**ONE:**
As you can see in the example, for some reason Ember doesn't like properties starting with uppercase characters. In the example, `Subject` doesn't get rendered but `subjectInLowercase` does.

The API that I request data from always send data in this uppercase notation and I have no control over it. Currently I'm working around this by passing the data to a method that converts all the properties to camelCase. Fortunately, the server doesn't care if I send the data back in camelCase. How do I fix this?

**TWO:** 
I need to modify some properties in the data before rendering them. In the example, I added a new property called `formattedDate`. This is the modified version of the `Timestamp` field. I usually use a Handlebars helper to do this formatting but this time, it is an input field. I don't want this `formattedDate` property going back to the server when the model is updated. Is there any better way than updating their relevant properties in the model and then manually deleting these extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your format date logic in the controller since controller is a proxy for model.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  getFormattedDate: function(){
    return moment(this.get('model.Timestamp')).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

  }.property('id'),

  actions: {
    updateForm: function() {
      var data = this.get('model');
      console.log(data);
      // Post this model back to the server
    }
  }
});
```

And in the view use

```
Formatted Date: {{input value=getFormattedDate}}
```

Comment: Hi, This works well for rendering but how do I update the date in the model to keep it in sync with the input field? Should I just do it manually before pushing the data? It just bugs me that Ember's native data-binding can't help in this scenario. Also, can you suggest any solution for my first issue?